# Nested new $loop function Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

I wanted to assign a property to the first element of each serie (Value1) and y tried to do with the new Laravel $loop variable but nesting doesn't work. I tried to use $loop->first, but only works one on the first Group.

I tried to do the next:

```
- Group 1     $loop->index = 0 (parent)
  - Value 1   $loop->index = 0
  - Value 2   $loop->index = 1
  - Value 3   $loop->index = 2

- Group 2     $loop->index = 1 (parent)
  - Value 1   $loop->index = 3
  - Value 2   $loop->index = 4
```

Seems the $loop->index (child) doesn't start a new serie.
What can I do?

Comment: You should show your code, because it works as expected with simple nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($groups as $group)
    <h3>Group {{ $group->name }}</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>SubGroup Name</td>
        </tr>
    @foreach($projects as $project)
        <tr>
            @if($loop->first)
                <td rowspan="{{ $loop->count }}"></td>
            @endif
            <td>Target Language</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>
@endforeach
```